# How to make two feature layers congruent using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, feature-class, spatial-adjustment

I have two feature layers (polyline/polygon) which should be congruent but there's an offset of about 220 meters.

The Georeferencing tool only works with raster layers.

How do I do the equivalent with a feature layer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ArcMap use the [Spatial Adjustment](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-existing-features/about-spatial-adjustment.htm) toolbar:

> Within the editing environment, the spatial adjustment tools provide
>   interactive methods to align and integrate your data. Spatial
>   adjustment supports a variety of adjustment methods and will adjust
>   all editable data sources. It's often used when you've imported data
>   from another source, such as a CAD drawing.